# Provisional headers are shown - Nodemailer - AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, request, nodemailer

The request header always give me the warning: Provisional headers are shown.
I cant figure out why i get this issue. Due to this warning the readyState doesnt change and my callbacks on the eventhandler onreadystatechange wont trigger. I guess it has something to with the application/json request header but i havent found a solution yet.
Hope someone of you has an idea what could solve this.
My AJAX Code:

```
export default function ajax() {
  const form = document.forms[0];

  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // FORMDATA TO JSON OBJECT
    const fields = document.querySelectorAll('form > div');
    let formData = {};
    fields.forEach((container) => {
      formData[container.childNodes[0].name] = container.childNodes[0].value;
    })
    const formDataJSON = JSON.stringify(formData);

    xhr.open('POST', '/send', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(this.readyState === this.DONE && this.status === 200)
        console.log('success');

      else if(this.readyState === this.UNSET)
        console.log('failed');

      else if(this.readyState === this.LOADING)
        console.log('loading');
    }

    xhr.send(formDataJSON);
  })
}
```

Nodemailer:

```
module.exports = (data) => {
  const _auth = require('./_auth');
  const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
      user: _auth.user,
      pass: _auth.pass
    }
  });

  const html = `
    <div style="background-color: #F3F4F7; border-radius: 10px; padding: 50px;">
      <h2>Sie haben eine neue Nachricht</h2>
      <p>${data.nachricht}</p>
      <h3>Absender</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>Name: ${data.name}</li>
        <li>Email: ${data.email}</li>
        <li>Tel: ${data.tel}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  `;

  const mailOptions = {
    from: data.email,
    to: _auth.user,
    subject: '20° - Nachricht',
    text: data.nachricht,
    html
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if (error) 
      console.log(error);
    else 
      console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);

    transporter.close();
  });
}
```

Comment: "Due to this error" — What error? The "Provisional headers are shown" warning is not an error but probably has the same root cause as the problem you are asking about.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, I mean the warning "Provional headers are shown".  -- corrected

Answer (score 0):

add header:

```
let config = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
    }
```